# Как выполнить действия после функции load

Tags: jquery

Имеется такой код:

```js
$(document).on('click','.read-more',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   let data = curCount;

   $(".content").append($('<div>').load("/admin/viewBanners",{action:"loadContent", id:data}));
   if(curCount + count <= total)
    curCount = curCount + count;
   else
    curCount = total;
   $('#info-count-total').html(' ('+curCount+' из '+total+')');
  });
```

Когда нажимается в таблице ссылка, то выполняется эта функция. Проблема в том, что если быстро нажать два раза на ссылку, то последняя строчка выполнится два раза и только потом выполняется функция load. Как сделать, что бы последняя строчка срабатывала после load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".content").append($('<div>').load("/admin/viewBanners",
  {action:"loadContent", id:data}, function() {
  if (curCount + count <= total)
    curCount = curCount + count;
  else
    curCount = total;
  $('#info-count-total').html(' ('+curCount+' из '+total+')');
}));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! То что нужно. Через 6 минут можно принять ответ